# OR condition in dataframe full outer join reducing performance spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I'm seeing that if my join condition involves OR clause, it takes a long time vs having an AND clause. I'm doing fullouter join.

My unit test doesn't show a major difference but when run against a large dataset, it runs very slow

```
df1.join(df2, expr("id1 = id2 AND amount1 = amount2"), "fullouter").cache()
```

The following runs for long time i.e. magnitude of ~10 times slower

```
df1.join(df2, expr("id1 = id2 OR amount1 = amount2"), "fullouter").cache()
```

any thoughts?

Comment: Since in AND condition, if the first condition is not satisfied, the next condition is not checked.
Whereas in OR condition,, even if the first condition is false, there is a possibility for the result to be true if the second condition is true.
Also, this involves outer join and hence you are seeing this vast difference in the run time.

Comment: Seems like an answer

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR** Performance difference between these two is expected.

- Logical conjunction (`AND`) can be expressed as a shuffle based-operation (either  sort merge join or shuffle hash join) - this means that each record has to be transferred to only one child partition, based on hash of all expressions included in the join condition.

  While in the worst case scenario (all join keys being constant and matching between both datasets) it can take N*M comparisons with all records shuffled to a single partition, typical scenarios, with real-life data, should be much more efficient, making roughly N + M comparisons.
- Logical disjunction (`OR`) cannot be expressed as a simple shuffle-based operation as records hashing to different buckets can be matched*. Therefore Spark uses Cartesian product followed by selection always transferring each record multiple times and making N*M comparisons.